# Connect aws elastic search 7.x with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, amazon-opensearch, resthighlevelclient

I tried connecting aws elasticsearch with spring boot through spring-elasticsearch-data and various other libraries but i get invalid bridge or oss flavor error. Any help in connecting them

Comment: what versions of Spring Boot, Spring Data Elasticsearch do you use?

Comment: Spring boot version 2.6.7, I need to integrate it with aws elastic search which gives 7.1 to 7.10 .SO what version of aws elastic search and spring-data-elastic search should i use to make them compactable.

 Version Spring Data Elasticsearch: 4.1.0
 Version Elasticsearch Client in build: 7.9.3
Version Elasticsearch Client used: 7.15.2
 Version mismatch in between Elasticsearch Clients build/use: 7.9.3 - 7.15.2

Sample error log

Comment: I think Elasticsearch added these checks in the 7 versions to make sure that their client libraries are only used for their products. You might check the OpenSearch spring-data project (https://github.com/opensearch-project/spring-data-opensearch) which is derived from spring-data-elasticsearch; their client might be able to handle this connection.